# Having trouble Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, getattribute

So the HTML consists of a table grid of SVG rect (squares though, so equal height and width) elements.

On click, each individual square can toggle between being 100px and 50px, using the code below:

```js
function clickChng() {
// Targets the svg rectangle being clicked
 var recwidth = event.target.getAttribute("width");
// if already 100px it changes it to 50px
 if (recwidth == 100) {
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 50);
 event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 50);
 event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 25);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 25);
 }
// otherwise, changes it back to 100px, which is the only other case
 else {
 event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
 event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
 event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 0);
 }
}
```

I need a function which can identify when all of the squares are in a particular state, width = 50px.

So far I have been trying to use the .every() array method but have been getting nowhere with it, just wondering if someone could shed some light on how I would go about doing this?

The main issue I'm facing seems to be that using the every() method requires another function, and I don't want to nest a function inside clickChng(), yet I want the function which checks all the squares to run every time a square is clicked in case it is the last one which completes the set.

Here's where I got to creating functions:

```js
function checkAll(sqrs) {
  if (sqrs.getAttributeNode("width").value == 50) {
  alert("Complete!");
  }
 }
 
 //reca is an array which recturns all the rect elements
 
 reca.every(checkAll)
```

Here's the full code, it appears lengthy but is actually very simple to get your head around. The table elements make up most of the code:

```js
var reca = document.getElementsByClassName("recel");
//New function to alter the properties of the rectangles globally
function changeprops() {

  //Loop globally Changes the attributes of the RECTANGLE element
  for (var i = 0; i < reca.length; i++) {
    var za = reca[i];
    za.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
    za.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
    za.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0);
    za.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 0);
    za.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'rgb(0, 150, 199)');
  }

  var svga = document.getElementsByClassName("svgel");
  //Loop globally hanges the attributes of the SVG element
  for (var i = 0; i < svga.length; i++) {
    var zb = svga[i];
    zb.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
    zb.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
  }
} //End Function

function clickChng() {
  // Targets the svg rectangle being clicked
  var recwidth = event.target.getAttribute("width");
  // if already 100px it changes it to 50px
  if (recwidth == 100) {
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 50);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 50);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 25);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 25);
  }
  // otherwise, changes it back to 100px, which is the only other case
  else {
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0);
    event.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 0);
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: none;
}


/* without this, the SVG element produces 5px whitespace at the bottom of itself */

.svgel {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body onload="changeprops()">
  <table id="tab1">

    <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ROW 2 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ROW 3 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ROW 4 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ROW 5 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg class="svgel" width="0" height="0">
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng()"></rect></svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: As an aside: `Element.setAttributeNS(null, ...` === `Element.setAttribute(...`. Also, global `event` variable is not defined in the specs and you will face issues in some browser not following all IE weird ideas.

Comment: @Kaiido, Firstly thank you for your input, I really appreciate it! can you elaborate on what you mean by 'global event variable is not defined in the specs'?. Are you referring to the scope of certain variables?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty specific thing you want to accomplish. Best that I could figure out without touching clickChng() function is adding another function to the onclick event for every rect. As shown here:

```
<rect  class="recel" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="clickChng();checkAll();"></rect>
```

Then adding this function:

```
    function checkAll(){
    var test = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < reca.length; i++) {
        if(reca[i].getAttributeNS(null, 'width') != 50)
            {
                test = false;
            }
        }
        if(test){
            console.log("Complete!")
        }
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ok, so I can run two functions with the same onclick? Wasn't aware I could do that.

Comment: Ante, just wanted to take the time to say thank you for your response. I've added it into my script and it works nicely.I think I'll avoid using the .every() function for the time being until I know how to use it properly.

Comment: No problem friend. You can always vote up if my post helped you. That's how stack overflow usually works, upto you. Good luck with JS can be tricky some times.